# Is the computer freezing due to high temperature?

Tags: windows-xp, cpu, freeze

The problem is that my computer suddenly freezes, the mouse and keyboard halt and nothing works.

So I checked the CPU temperature, and I found that under BIOS H/W monitoring

```
CPU Temperature -> 94+ -105 Deg C
Internal Temperature -> 45+ Deg C
Remote Temperature  -> 45+ Deg C
```

Here are computer specs :

```
Intel Pentium 4 3.0 Ghz
Windows xp sp3
1 GB RAM
256MB Graphics card
```

I don't have very many programs installed except Visual Studio 2010 , some multimedia players, etc.

Is it OK? Do I need to change thermal paste again?

Comment: thats way hot, you can boil water on your CPU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temperatures like that can definitely be the cause of poor system performance.

You could look into [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php) to monitor your temperatures while you figure out what's wrong. 100<sup>o</sup>C can't be good for anything. It's also good to get a second opinion before you go out and spend money.

First thing I would do is check the cooling/Unit or fan that came with your processor; if you didn't get one you should invest in one.

Check the ventilation of your case, make sure it's not being blocked. I don't know what else is inside the case but if it's cramped - big PSU, speedy HDD, and a big graphics card - then you can be generating a ton of heat.

If you built the computer yourself or updated a stock computer with some spiffy components you may also want to look into a more ventilated case.

**To summarize I would:**

1. Check with SpeedFan
2. Check the CPU fan/coooling unit
3. Test better ventilation methods (move case, open case, new fans)
4. Buy a new case with better fans, vent, etc

Answer (score 3):

95-105<sup>o</sup>C is a very, very high temperature for a P4 to be running at, probably near the maximum it can withstand without critically failing. I would take the case off the computer and see if the whole computer needs a clean. Re-applying thermal paste could also be an idea, and consider investing in a new system fan.

Comment: Whats the diff btw CPU Temperature and  Internal Temperature?. Is it CPU Temperature = Internal Temperature + Remote Temperature ?

Comment: CPU tempeture would probably be the temperature of the chip, while internal termperature is the air temperature inside the case. At your current amount, if you poured water on your processor (**DO NOT DO THIS**) it would *boil the water*.

Comment: so tell me what's the normal temperature for P4 ?

Comment: Depends on the model of the processor, but the hottest I've seen is 60C.

Comment: I am not sure about your answer : i think Internal Temperature must not go beyond 60 . The reason i am saying all this due to event log in BIOS isn't showing any CPU thermal trip.

Answer (score 2):

The temperatures you are experiencing on your chip are too high.

From [here](http://www.motherboardpoint.com/working-temperature-range-p4-t151115.html):

> The temp can vary by 5-10C based on the specific CPU core and
>   frequency. See http://www.intel.com for the specifics per each CPU. In
>   general, the max temp is around 85-90C, but the maximum temp at which
>   one can expect stable operation (at stock speeds) is closer to 70C, a
>   little higher for the lower speeds in each family and a little higher
>   for the upper speeds per family.
>
> Recommended temps are dependent on the application- one cannot
>   realistically expect some configurations (particuarly low-profile
>   chassis) to provide as much airflow or heatsink clearance as larger
>   chassis. A ballpark might be 46C, in a typical 24C room. IE- 22C over
>   the ambient temp, so if your ambient were 30C, it'd be expected that
>   CPU temp rises to 52C. As a processor's frequency increases (with all
>   other things remaining equal) the heat also linearly increases, so the
>   upper speed Prescotts would have a bit more than 22C rise over
>   ambient.

I would support Tom's ideas of cleaning the case, reapplying thermal paste but also add to check that any fans you have are running and are unobstructed.